# Hausman test showing different results between R and Stata

Tags: r, panel-data, stata, plm, hausman

I ran a Hausman test to compare random and fixed effects regression for a panel dataset in both R and Stata and found that the two are showing different results. The troubling thing is that the Stata using `hausman` is saying to use Random `(p>0.05)` while R using `phtest` is telling me to use fixed effects `(p<0.05)`.

Including options in Stata such as `sigmamore` or `sigmaless` still shows different data. In R, changing methods and adding `vcov` functions produces the same result. I tried searching online, but I couldn't find any information on this discrepancy. I have a unbalanced panel with n=154 and t=5-227, N=14469.

**R:**

```
fixed <- plm(y ~ x1 + x2, data=panel, model="within")
random <- plm(y ~ x1 + x2, data=panel, model="random")
phtest (fixed, random)
```

**Stata:**

```
xtreg y x1 x2, fe
estimates store fixed
xtreg y x1 x2, re
estimates store random
hausman fixed random
```

**R:**

```
phtest(fixed, random)

    Hausman Test
    data:  y~ x1 + x2
    chisq = 7.1728, df = 2, p-value = 0.0277
    alternative hypothesis: one model is inconsistent
```

**Stata:**

````
hausman fixed random

                 ---- Coefficients ----
             |      (b)          (B)            (b-B)     sqrt(diag(V_b-V_B))
             |     fixed        random       Difference          S.E.
        -----+----------------------------------------------------------------
        x1   |    .1337018     .1342335       -.0005318        .0004202

        x2   |    .4369113     .4353527        .0015586        .0006969
        ------------------------------------------------------------------------
        b = consistent under Ho and Ha; obtained from xtreg
        B = inconsistent under Ha, efficient under Ho; obtained from xtreg

    Test:  Ho:  difference in coefficients not systematic

                  chi2(2) = (b-B)'[(V_b-V_B)^(-1)](b-B)
                          =        5.33
                Prob>chi2 =      0.0696
```
````

Comment: Are the coefficient estimates the same?  Are the standard errors the same?

Comment: The fixed effects are exactly the same for the coefficients and standard errors, z, R-squared. The random effects model does have very small marginal differences at the 0.0001 level and below in the coefficients and F values. For instance, .1342335 vs .1343086 for coefficients; .005323 vs .0053257. Does this marginal difference suggest different assumptions in the random model? If so, do you know how to control for them and produce the same results?

Comment: See plm's vignette https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/plm/vignettes/B_plmFunction.html under chapter "unbalanced panels" on why the coefficients of the random effect models diverge for Stata vs. plm.